# VBA Excel Export Listbox Results to HTML

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export the results of the list box to  HTML file, but just by exporting the first column, I would like to export the results from the listbox as well. anyone help me?

Code :

```
Private Sub CreateHTML()

  'Create an .html file in the assigned directory.
  Dim sFile As Variant

   sFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="HTML Files (*.html), *.htm")

  'Open up the temp HTML file and format the header.
  Open sFile For Output As #1
  Print #1, "<html>"
  Print #1, "<head>"
  Print #1, "<style type=""text/css"">"
  Print #1, "table {font-size: 16px;font-family: Optimum, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse}"
  Print #1, "tr {border-bottom: thin solid #A9A9A9;}"
  Print #1, "td {padding: 4px; margin: 3px; padding-left: 20px; width: 75%; text-align: justify;}"
  Print #1, "th { background-color: #A9A9A9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 28px; text-align: center;}"
  Print #1, "td:first-child { font-weight: bold; width: 25%;}"
  Print #1, "</style>"
  Print #1, "</head>"
  Print #1, "<body>"
  Print #1, "<table class=""table""><thead><tr class=""firstrow""><th colspan=""2"">RESULTS</th></tr></thead><tbody>"

 
     
     Dim i As Long
     Dim strFind As String
     For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        'EDIT HERE TO CHANGE IT TO YOUR LINKING
        Print #1, "<tr><td>"
        Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        Print #1, "</td><td>"
        Print #1, "</td></tr>"
    Next i


  'Add ending HTML tags
  Print #1, "</body>"
  Print #1, "</html>"
  Close
  End Sub
```

Link to download:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19IxHZKVe7u1vWW03TKqiEOQscUkbcEsC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code exports the results from the list box, but you want the results from the listbox as well? Are you talking about a different listbox? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your excel file you wrote this line in the loop

```
Print #1, strFind = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
```

the result of [ strFind = Me.ListBox1.List(i) ]  is false  and that is written to the file.

but in your code you wrote

```
Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i)
```

the last code is working O.K  , just change the code in the excel....

UPDATE :
if you need all columns then

```
Print #1, "<tr><td>"
Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i,1)
Print #1, "</td><td>"
Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i,2)
Print #1, "</td><td>"
Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i,3)
Print #1, "</td><td>"
Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i,....)
Print #1, "</td></tr>"
```

Comment: Yeah , but this code: Print #1, Me.ListBox1.List(i)  just export the first column, I need to export all Listbox values.